# The redundant boolean

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

Classically, booleans are one bit; `true` or `false`, `1` or `0`. Leading zeros would just be redundant. For example, `001` means the same as `00001` or just `1`.

## The 32-bit boolean

Given a truthy/falsey value, output the equivalent 32-bit boolean as a string.
 (Or as a number if for *some reason* your language supports leading zeros.)

**Your program doesn't have to work for every truthy/falsy type, only what your programming language work best for.**

## Example i/o

```
Input >> Output

truthy >> 00000000000000000000000000000001
falsey >> 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytes wins!

Comment: Do we need to handle any possible truthy or falsey value, or just booleans?

Comment: If my language supports types and has boolean can I use 1's (int) as truthy?

Comment: @LiefdeWen of course

Comment: No longer duplicate as truthy/falsy inputs can be differen't for each answer/language.

Comment: I don't see why but huh, okay ~

Comment: Is there a language in which the test cases `truthy` and `falsey` would be valid?

Comment: Some languages use `-1` for true, i.e. all bits are set to `1` and the number is recognised as a signed integer.

Comment: @CJDennis Right, I'm positive Python is one of those languages.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>33</s> <s>25</s> <s>18</s> 15 bytes

Thanks @jurjen-bos for the `__mod__` tip.

```python
'%.32d'.__mod__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX11Vz9goRV0vPj43PyU@/n9BUWZeiUaahqGmJheMbYDEDikqTUXiuiXmFAP5/wE)

Comment: Would `lambda b:'%0.32d'%b` work?

Comment: Oh, is `None` *truthy* or *falsy*?

Comment: @BruceForte Falsey

Comment: also 25 bytes, but for python3.6+: `lambda b:f'{bool(b):032}'` or `lambda b:f'{not b<1:032}'`

Comment: You can save 1 byte by removing the leading zero in `0.32d`.

Answer (score 10):

## x86-16 Machine Code (DOS), 16 bytes

```
B4 02          mov  ah,  2
B2 30          mov  dl, '0'
B9 1F 00       mov  cx, 31

            PrintZeros:
CD 21          int  0x21
E2 FC          loop PrintZeros

00 CA          add  dl, bl
CD 21          int  0x21
C3             ret
```

The above function receives a boolean value (0 == falsey, 1 == truthy) in the `BL` register (low byte of `BX`), and prints a "redundant boolean" string to the standard output.

It works by invoking an interrupt (0x21) to make a DOS function call (selected by setting `AH` to 2) that prints a single character (in `DL`) to the standard output.

First, the ASCII character '0' is loaded into `DL`, the counter (`CX`) is set to 31, and it loops to print the "redundant" bytes. Then, the input boolean value is added to `DL` (if `BL` is falsey, adding 0 will leave `DL` unchanged as ASCII '0'; if `BL` is truthy, `DL` will be incremented by one to ASCII '1'), and the final byte is printed.

The function does not return a value.

Pretty decent for a language that doesn't really do strings.

---

#### Full Program, 21 bytes

If you want to make it into a full program, only 5 more bytes are required. Instead of passing the input in a register, this reads the input from the arguments passed on the command line when invoking the application. An argument of 0 is interpreted as falsey, as is the complete lack of arguments; an argument greater than 0 is interpreted as truthy.

Simply assemble the following code as a COM program, and then execute it on the command line.

```
B4 02            mov   ah,  2
B2 30            mov   dl, '0'
B9 1F 00         mov   cx, 31

               PrintZeros:
CD 21            int   0x21
E2 FC            loop  PrintZeros

3A 16 82 00      cmp   dl, BYTE PTR [0x82]  ; compare to 2nd arg, at offset 0x82 in PSP
D6               salc                       ; equivalent to sbb al, al
28 C2            sub   dl, al
CD 21            int   0x21
C3               ret                        ; you can simply 'ret' to end a COM program
```

Sample Output:

```
C:\>bool.com
00000000000000000000000000000000
C:\>bool.com 0
00000000000000000000000000000000
C:\>bool.com 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 
C:\>bool.com 2
00000000000000000000000000000001
C:\>bool.com 7
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

How does it work? Well, it's basically the same thing, until you get down to the `CMP` instruction. This compares the command-line argument with the value of the `DL` register (which, you recall, contains an ASCII '0'). In a COM program, the bytes of code are loaded at offset 0x100. Preceding that is the [program segment prefix (PSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix), which contains information about the state of a DOS program. Specifically, at offset 0x82, you find the first (actually the second, since the first is a space) argument that was specified on the command line when the program was invoked. So, we are just comparing this byte against an ASCII '0'.

The comparison sets the flags, and then the `SALC` instruction (an undocumented opcode prior to the Pentium, equivalent to `sbb al, al`, but only 1 byte instead of 2) sets `AL` to 0 if the two values were equal, or -1 if they were different. It is then obvious that when we subtract `AL` from `DL`, this results in either ASCII '0' or '1', as appropriate.

(Note that, somewhat ironically, you will break it if you pass an argument with a leading 0 on the command line, since it looks only at the first character. So `01` will be treated as falsey. :-)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda n:'0'*31+'01'[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSt1AXcvYUFvdwFA9Oi/2f0FRZl6JRpqGW2JOcaqmJheMH1JUCuT@BwA)

Comment: `'10'[not n]` would suffice if those need to be supported.

Comment: `'{:032}'.format` for 15 bytes and work the same as your current solution

Comment: @rosslh `bool(n)` would be sufficient

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript, 23 bytes

```
a=>'0'.repeat(31)+ +!!a
```

`!!a` coerces a into a boolean, which the unary plus turns into an int.

Comment: `a=>'0'.repeat(31)+(+a)` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @Cowsquack that fails on strings, empty arrays, NaN,functions, and other values where the coercion into an number doesn't result in 0 or 1

Comment: also empty objects, arrays, Infinity and undefined

Comment: ... but now ... `Your program doesn't have to work for every truthy/falsy type, only what your programming language work best for.`

Comment: `a=>'0'.repeat(31)+~~a` does work with true,false,1,0

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 8 bytes

```
32é0Àñl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39jo8EqDww2HNzLm/P//3wAA)

Explanation:

```
32é0            " Insert 32 '0's
    Àñ          " Arg1 times...
      <C-a>     "   Increment the number under the cursor
           l    "   Move one char to the right. This will break the loop since there is 
                "   no more room on this line
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

```
ᛝΨβ_I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@HsuedWnNsU7/n/vyEA)

Explanation:

```
 ᛝ        # Constant 31
  Ψ       # Apply next token to all in list
    β     # Constant 0
     _    # Push each element to stack
      I   # Take Line of input.
```

Saved a byte thanks to *Okx*

Comment: 5 bytes - [`ᛝΨβ_I`](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@HsuedWnNsU7/n/vyEA "Neim – Try It Online")

Comment: `ᛝ` isn't on the wiki, where did you find it?

Comment: It's on the [list of variables](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP0PBP/yC0oy8/OK/@uWAQA "Neim – Try It Online")

Comment: @Okx Okay, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes

```matlab
@(n)dec2bin(n,32)
```

Anonymous function. Works in MATLAB too.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjTzMlNdkoKTNPI0/H2Ejzf5pGSVFpqiZXmkZaYk5xquZ/AA)

Comment: I'll be damned...

Answer (score 4):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 369 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE A
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS A
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE A
TALK TO THE HAND "00000000000000000000000000000001"
BULLSHIT
TALK TO THE HAND "00000000000000000000000000000000"
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVC7bsMwDNz1FQcvWd1PoGXGIqKHK1I1PBbNWLRA/x9w5SzZCpQTcS8c@f7z9f15/zgOsYtCQ9lMErvAO3yoopZIYZUZ5PbSoGxoirZidEvfO1ZB2jUFiap22Vwghlw2J9go20mR3k4pCFPLPqBc8dpYTUruljzjKQ30xrDAqeO6ceVOpsSzkHHc3cSemjLkkrAUycvpUdqxRiY9axrF2wn2jB7Ws4fx73kZ3NRi1CD2f/M4PP7yaJ0LKuvK3nAtFbEs4p/sxJxhXJPkfsp8HOMv)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 36 bytes

```
++++[>++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>-[>.<-]>>,.
```

<s>I'm sure there is a clever way of not moving around so much with the pointers.</s>

I was right. There were. Thanks to @Graviton for giving me the idea!

Next step: Get the values 32 and 48 quicker!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwii7UCkjW6sHYgF4tiAOLrRdnpAWkfv/38DAA)

```
++++        - Increment 1st slot by 4
[           - Loop until 4 becomes 0
    >++++   - Add 4 to 2nd slot
    <-      - Decrement loop
]           - At this point, we point to slot 1 and slot 2 contains 16, which is the Greatest Common Divisor of 48 (value 0 in ASCII) and 32 (final length of answer)
>           - Point to value 16 (slot 2)
[           - Start loop to get our target values 32 and 48
    >++     - Point to slot 3 and multiply 16 by 2 = 32
    >+++    - Point to slot 4 and multiply 16 by 3 = 48
    <<-     - Decrement the loop so that slot 2 becomes 0
]           - We now point slot 2
>-          - Move to slot 3 and remove one so we can spam (output) 31 zeroes
[           - Start outputting until slot 3 is empty
    >.      - Move to slot 4 where our ASCII value for 0 is
    <-      - Decrement the loop so that slot 3 becomes 0
]           - We are now at slot 3 and it is empty.
,.          - We can now gather input from the user and output it.
```

Was fun for a first Golf!

<s>It has gotten way too late now.</s> What am I even doing

Comment: Thanks to entropy, I made it 1 byte shorter to get to the number 16.

Comment: Just for fun here's a 60 byte version: `>-[-[-<]>>+<]>--<<-[>+<-----]>--->[-<.>],.` (takes input as 0 or 1) [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xCsMwDEV3nUJbWlqFhnboYHSRkMExLjEFN9jy@R05HUohT6Dh6/E1Jxviq7h3rUyjjpmYL7qI0CVvxaMsHt0nZrFR8D6AMUCjOtRoIuGh@njiaQ8Wm5z4hN2tOwOD/uh5wh9rCntzEzLCtcd/vveStSLEtUitwwY)

Comment: Well, thanks so much @Graviton. You made me realize that I was putting way too much effort in dropping the ASCII value to 0 while I just had to output it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
#␟>[0_]N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fWd4u2iA@1u/////mAA)

`␟` is a Unit Separator, ASCII `0x1F`, or 31. Can't find the actually character to paste into TIO, so TIO instead uses `# 1-`, which pushes space (32) and decrements to 31.

### Explanation

```
#␟>[0_]N  Implicit input from commandline args
#␟        Push unit separator (31)
   >       Move top item to bottom of stack
    [..]   Loop, runs 31 times
     0_    Print 0
        N  Boolean conversion, truthy values become 1, falsey values become 0
           Implicit output of top of stack
```

Comment: Here is the tio link with the 0x1F character in it [TIO](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fWd4u2iA@1u/////mAA)

Comment: @PunPun1000 Oh thanks! I'll update the post

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 32 bytes

Sorry but I was forced to do it in 32 bytes >_<

```
var s=t
for(u<-0 to 30)s="0"+s
s
```

It's enclosed by a function taking `t` as parameter (as a `string` that can be "0" or "1" for resp. falsy or truthy), and `s` is returned.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzcWZkpqmUJJvbJSkUWIVXFKUmZeuCaVtq/@XJRYpFNuWcKXlF2mU2ugaAFUqGBtoFtsqGShpF3MV/6/l4ioAqi3JydNQMlTQtVNQ0oYYpmSopKmJkDNAkTMAydX@BwA)

## Valid response : Scala, 46 bytes

Same as my java response, I was supposed to take a boolean for the parameter. So :

```
var s=if(t)"1"else"0"
for(u<-0 to 30)s="0"+s
s
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwEADP5hVLTgmlkNpbsYLePfmCtN1IJSQluxWh9O0xB0GvM8zQaL3NcXjiyHCzcwB8M4aJ4LIsmzhM6IBjexwUd9cYPdqguzunOTz6Lb9sAupnp1jLRqInlEYKF5NaT7UpIbRGU19gRYLyLsRSSvZByQbqM8jq@04rav2T5l86W77F7vkD)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```
b->"".format("%032d",b?1:0)
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwEEX3PcUQEFKwoepOUU9gNy7FxSRNJTVNSjMtiPTsNdpuhZnF8P/jTY0DZr7Vri6fk7IYAlzQuHcCYBzprkKlofieAFfqjHuA4tJ7q9GBTA8xGOPGCYRkFBTg4AiTzE6Micp3DRJnq3y3Ldlanjf7PJ0OM9D20kZg4QZvSmiims@a2x0wXbyvQLoRvifRxois404oTl2v098HfysV2rB0xmScPg)

Comment: Yep, still here to outgolf you: `"".format` ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That was it! Damn I'm stupid.. xD When I was typing `String.format` I knew there was a shorter way somehow, but I thought I probably used a String variable last time... Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 23 bytes

```matlab
@(x)[48+[!(1:31),x],'']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzOiU12SgpM0/DQMfYUFOnQtvEIvZ/mkZJUWmqJleaRlpiTnGq5n8A)

This is shorter than all the approaches I tried with `printf`. I might have missed something though, since I did this on my phone.

Only one byte longer

```matlab
@(x)[dec2bin(0,31),x+48]
```

This could be 18 bytes if I could take 1/0 as strings.

```matlab
@(x)[48+!(1:31),x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Iz2sRCW1HD0MrYUFOnIvZ/moa6obomF5AyUNf8DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
¾31×«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0D5jw8PTD63@/98QAA)

Comment: Smarter than `31úð0:`!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 21 bytes

Yeah, that space needs to be there.. :/

```
->x{"%032b"%(x ?1:0)}
```

In Ruby *everything* except `false` and `nil` is truthy;
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTdCkAwGAbgW3lbKeqj4UzhElyAHJi2EBKbn3Dts4Pn2Yy4rcptWFwP83iaCOb5F8o448FnV6N31MswEVQ77ZKgN@PmhJiQEBhz@sFdiVF2Olrk2URzu@LBe7xQ9dHgsz8)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
""<>ToString/@PadLeft[{Boole@#},31]&
```

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
Row@PadLeft[{Boole@#},31]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KL/cISAxxSc1rSS62ik/PyfVQblWx9gwVu1/QFFmXomCQ5qCQ0hRaSoXguuWmFOMzNcwtDPQROHbGGj@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```hs
(('0'<$[1..31])++).show.fromEnum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzX0ND3UDdRiXaUE/P2DBWU1tbU684I79cL60oP9c1rzT3f25iZp6CrUJuYoFvvIJGQWlJcEmRT55emqZCtFtiTnGqTkhRaWrsfwA)

Thanks @nimi for `-5` bytes!

Comment: `show(fromEnum x)` instead of `last(...)`. Pointfree even shorter: `(('0'<$[1..31])++).show.fromEnum`.

Comment: @nimi Didn't know that `Bool` is an `Enum`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 29 bytes

```
a=>new string('0',31)+(a?1:0)
```

OP said 1/0 can be used for truthy/falsey, so can make `a` an int and it becomes

```
a=>new string('0',31)+a
```

C# doesn't really have truthy/falsey though so I will not use this answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xCsIwFEX3fMXbTLBKi5u1dRCcFAQHB3F4xrQE0gTyUkWk317T1tU73nMuXEkL6bzqW9K2hvObgmpyxqRBIjh5V3ts2IdBDAUMWsLT6QccUVtOwcfR9QboaxKjM5lD9q2Vm7tzJoHJK6GKFRTAgPVYlFa9foTP0lmyysSc4zZbp6KPB3bOkjNqefE6qIO2ig9rHnyrhMj/4QoNjTwe6FjH@i8)

Comment: I don't think the second one is valid. Integers are neither truthy nor falsey in C#, only bools are.

Comment: @Mayube I did ask and OP said its okay, but I kinda agree with you so will edit.

Comment: Annoyingly `Padleft` comes in at the same byte count here.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Started with PadLeft as well :)

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but `interpolated strings` can be quite useful here: `b=>$"{(b?1:0):D32}"` `19 bytes`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
?1:0 ¤i31ç0
```

### Explanation:

```
?1:0 ¤i31ç0
?              // If the input is a truthy, return:
 1             //   1
  :0           //   Else, 0
     ¤         // Convert to a base-2 string
      i        // Insert at index 0:
       31ç0    //   A string filled with 0s, length 31
```

Saved a byte using a base-2 conversion built-in!

To insert the string of 0s in front of the `1`/`0`, I need to cast the `1` and `0` into a string. The typical way of doing that would be `1s`  (3 bytes). But because we're only converting 1s and 0s, I can use the base-2 built-in `1¤` (2 bytes).

---

Input can be in the form of an integer or string.

`0` and `""` are falsy in Japt.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/397QykDh0JJMY8PDyw3@/zcEAA)

[Test suite](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9DiCHtDKwOFQ0syjQ0PLzf4/z9aSUlHKS0/X0nHQMcwVkE3CAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), <s>20</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
65*1+[0u1-]nu
```

EDIT: Saved 5 bytes thanks to ovs.
EDIT: Saved another 2 bytes by printing 0 as a number rather than a character.

Comment: Would `65*1+["0"o1-]nu` work?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

Thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer* for saving a byte!

Goes for the full program approach:

```python
print+bool(input(31*'0'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EOyk/P0cjM6@gtETD2FBL3UBdU/P/fxMA)

Comment: Replace `~~` with `+` for -1. After that [the full program will not be expensive anymore](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8nMTcpJVGhwkrdQF3L2FA7QTspPz9Ho0Iz4f///4YA). ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I didn't know that was possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
×0³¹Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMkMze1WEPdQF3H2FBT01oBIuqZV1BaElwCZKdrAEX//zf8r1v2X7c4BwA) (Link to the verbose version.)

As Charcoal understand `0` and `1` as `True` or `False`, this just prints 31 `0`s and the input (`0` or `1`) as string.

Comment: :P [That's actually correct](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPOqeGFJWm/v8PAA), I thought I made the variables stringify to `True` though, weird

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 40 chars, 40 bytes

This takes string as parameter, which is not correct (falsy/truthy java value is forced by OP to be represented by a boolean).

```
c->{for(int i=0;++i<32;c=0+c);return c;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xCsMgFEV3v@KRSQkNaTvadM/QqWPpYI0JpokGfQZK8NutlKzdLhzOPaNYxcEuyozdO8lJeA83oc1GtEHleiEVtBu5o9NmAKT7kIxHAkA8CtQSWgjQQJKH69ZbR7MKuql5WerL@cRlU5dZcAqDMyB5TJyQJbymbO4Hq9UdzLm7Bx5PEG7wLJc/HtVc2YDVkglOhoYKaVEXjPG/9PijkcT0BQ)

## Valid response : Java, 60 chars, 60 bytes

```
c->{String k="";for(k+=c?1:0;k.length()<32;k=0+k);return k;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xDsIgFAB3vuLFCWJsqm5ide7g5GgcnkgrgtDAw8Q0/fbaqKvzXS53xycuQqf9/WpH5TAlOKDxPTOedGxQaah7dqRofAvELyE4jR6UkANjiZCMghoyVDCqxa7/ibaazWQTIrfzSu2Xm1Lawmnf0o2L7XolbVXOrZBRU44erBxGyViXL26q/aLPYK7wmFb4t3k6A8Y2iWnmlUg/ipCp6CZCzvNcEG/QJS2E/Mcp5g8e2DC@AQ)

I know there is already a Java answer which is shorter than this one, but still :)

Comment: Yes, the `return` statement is part of your code, so part of your byte-count. But your answer doesn't fulfill the rules: you **must** get a `boolean` as input. "Truthy/falsy" is translated in Java as either `true` or `false`, and nothing else. So you can't get a `String` as input parameter.

Comment: I see. I'll modify it soon enough. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to put the final semicolon (`;`). Also, you can shorten your code like this: `c->{String k="";for(;k.length()<31;)k+=0;return k+=c?1:0;}`. The `k+=c?1:0` is to shorten `k+(c?1:0)`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks but why isn't the final semicolon mandatory?

Comment: It is mandatory, in the code, but not in the snippet. In the TIO, the footer can simply start with `;`. A statement requires a semicolon. A lambda is not a statement.

Comment: ahh so it's not in bytecount :)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave,<s>16</s> 11 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x(1:32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCs0LD0MrYSPN/mm1iXrE1V5qGkgF@YKikSYQqgxgDoLr/AA)

A function handle that takes `"00000000000000000000000000000001"` as truthy and
`"00000000000000000000000000000000\0"` as falsey.

Explanation:

In Octave an array is considered as falsey if at least one of its elements is zero. The 33th element of the second string is a character with the ASCII value of 0 so it can be considered as falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Unwanted, Unnecessary, Opportunistic](https://github.com/faso/Unwanted-Unnecessary-Opportunistic), 7 bytes

```
P0M31P*
```

Pass either 1 or 0 into the register.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 26 bytes

Pretty much the same idea as [1bluestone's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133327/63856), but in C it's shorter, and it does work correctly for any integer input:

```
f(a){printf("%032i",!!a);}
```

Of course, this includes some implicitly typed variables/functions as all good C-golf answers do... The `!!` operator is the shortest way to convert any truthy value to `1` in C (via double negation, `!` is defined to return either `1` or `0`).

Test with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
f(a){printf("%032i",!!a);}
int main() {
    f(0), printf("\n");
    f(1), printf("\n");
    f(2), printf("\n");
    f(-1), printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 28 bytes

```
<?=str_pad($argv[1],32,0,0);
```

Save as bool.php and run:

```
$ php bool.php 0
00000000000000000000000000000000
$ php bool.php 1
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: 3 bytes shorter: `printf('%032d',$argv[1]);` (requires the `-r` flag).

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/728aa9b047892569a2bd5a15d54c68dd3bae0bb2?at=master), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
BṄiℑpέ←←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638///D3KmrnR7ubMl81DKx4NzaR20TgOj/f8P/AA)

Explanation (codepage [with reasoning behind the character]/hex code):

```
: 1A - Push an integer from STDIN (lowercase integers)
B: 0B - Push 11 (B is 11 in hex)
Ṅ: 36 - Pop n; push the nth prime, 11th prime is 31 (Ṅ-th)
i: 49 - Pop n; push [1,...,n] (index/iota)
ℑ: 34 - Pop n; push imag(n) (ℑmaginary part, applied to each element, which gives 0 for real numbers)
p: 60 - Pop n; push stringified n (0=>"0" ... 35=>"Z", the b in base upside down)
έ: 56 - Pop n; push n joined by "" (έmpty string)
←: 26 - Pop n; output n with no newline (out←in)
←: 26 - Pop n; output n with no newline (out←in)
```

I can't believe that this is possible without any two-argument commands whatsoever!

Edit: Saved 1 byte by using primes instead of arithmetic to get 31.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia 0.6, 12 bytes

```
~x=bin(x,32)
```

Nothing clever here, there is basically a built in for it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌡Ö├⌡→
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f599c3f51a&i=1%0A0)

Numeric 0 and empty lists are considered falsy. All other values are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 82 bytes

```
     +          + + +  **      +*`      + *  + +.  + +', '.      +  ' `      +.  `
```

```
5+                 Push 0
10+1+1+2*0*6+0*    Push 31 (5*(5+1)+1)
0`                 [Label 0]
  6+1*             Subtract 1 from top of stack
  2+1+0.           Print '0'
  2+1+0'           If top is not zero, goto label 0
0,1'               If input is non-zero, goto label 1
  0.6+2'           Print '0', goto label 2
  1`6+0.           [Label 1] print '1'
2`                 [Label 2]
```

(The number before each symbol represents the number of spaces)

It's pretty straightforward: print 31 zeroes, then print zero if the input is zero, or one if the input is non-zero. Normally, you would need to push a zero to print on the eighth line, but I just used one the zero from the first half of the program. The [Label 2] at the end is important so that the falsey case doesn't fall into the truthy case, and instead jumps to the end.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLCqq/P9fAQS0FeBAGwwVtLSgXK0EmLgWWFIPTKrrKKjrwSQU1BVgioBiCf//mwAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
S32↳›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiUzMy4oaz4oC6IiwiIiwiMFxuMSJd)

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJTMzLihrPigLoiLCIiLCIwIl0=) for 5 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 11 bytes

```
⍕¯32↑1↑1\⍨⊢
```

**How?**

`1\⍨⊢` - repeat 1 input times - return empty array on falsy value

`1↑` - take the first item

`¯32↑` - align right with 31 zeros

`⍕` - format as string

Comment: Simply `⍕¯32↑⊢` should work

Comment: @Cowsquack & Uriel Neither works as they include spaces. You need `∊⍕¨¯32↑⎕` or something.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 11 bytes

```
(31#'0'),":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91WT0HD2FBZ3UBdU0fJiis1OSNfIV3BEMYw@P8fAA)

### how?

```
31 zeros
00...000  append     turn the 0 or 1 input into string
(31#'0')    ,       ":
```

note: in J, booleans are 0 or 1, also known as "the iverson convention," after ken iverson, creator of J and APL

Comment: I understand that 1 and 0 are booleans in J, but you're just appending the input to 31 0s. Shouldn't there be some form of boolean validation?

Comment: @Oliver The problem specifies "Given a truthy/falsey value..." so no, I don't think you should be validating... Also, note that `":` is required for this to work -- it changes a boolean to a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
31”0x⁸ṆṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Y8FHDXIOKR407Hu5sA6L///9HR8fGAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
+*31\0-1!
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2a31%5C0-1%21&input=%7B1%7D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%7B%7D%0A0%0A2%0A%5B3%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
+*31\0-1!
+*31\0-1!Q | Implicit Q (input)
 *31\0     | repeat the character '0' 31 times
        !Q | logical negation of input
      -1   | subtract from 1
+          | concatenate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
32&YB
```

Uses inputs `1`/ `0`, or `T`/ `F`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39hILdLp/39DAA)

#### Explanation

```
32     % Push 32
&YB    % Convert implicit input to binary with 32 digits. Gives char output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 7 bytes

```
0^*30^#
```

There is no truthy/falsey type in Carrot at the moment. However, `1` and `0` are usually considered to be truthy/falsey so that is how I am expecting the input.

Explanation:

```
0   //Set the string stack to 0
^   //Change to operations mode
*30 //Duplicate the string stack 30 times
^   //Convert to string stack mode
#   //Add the input to the end of the stack
    //Implicitly output the string stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

```
Ms`.+
^
31$*0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/ftzhBT5srjsvYUEXL4P9/AA) Assumes empty input is falsy and everything else is truthy, which is about all you can do when your only type is string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 30 bytes

```lua
("%032d"):format(b and 1 or 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/J8cS/2)

Comment: i'm afraid that's not currently valid, you need to submit a full program or function like [here](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ0nVwNgoRUnTKi2/KDexRENPTy8xL0XBUCG/SMFAU/P///@GpgYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
<n0v?)*3a:l
;oi<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3ybPoMxeU8s40SqHyzo/0@b/f0MA)

## Explanation

```
<n0v?)*3a:l
;oi<
<              | Move the direction left
         :l    | Push the length of the stack onto the stack and duplicate it
      *3a      | Push 10*3 onto the stack
     )         | Compare the stack top item is greater than the next stack item, push 1 is true else 0
   v?          | Check if stack top is 0, if 0 then jump else go to line 2
 n0            | Print 0 (this will then loop line 1 again)
;oi<           | Take input (1 byte), print input then end program
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 28 bytes

```
#(format "%031d" (if % 1 0))
```

Truthy is everything but `nil` and `false`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 25 bytes

```
v=>'0'.repeat(31)+(v?1:0)
```

31 zeroes and conditionally add a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```js
b=>`${+b}`.padStart(0,32)
```

A different approach. Takes input as specifically `true` or `false`.

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
b=>`${+b}`.padStart(32,0)

console.log(true, f(true))
console.log(false, f(false))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: `b=>'0'.repeat(31)+(+b)` is three bytes shorter.

Comment: @Cowsquack That's already done [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133299/69583); I decided to just demonstrate a different method.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 16 bytes

```
'0'k:'k,&!!+,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X91AXS7bCoh11BQVtXUc/v83NAIA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 2730 271e 6b3a 271e 6b2c 2621 212b 2c40  '0'.k:'.k,&!!+,@
```

---

**output as space sperated digits, 9 bytes:**

```
'k.&!!.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X10uW09NUVHP4f9/QyMA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 271e 6b2e 2621 212e 40                   '.k.&!!.@
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/dyvil) v0.33.0, 15 Bytes

```
b=>"0"*31+b?1:0
```

**Usage**:

```
let f: boolean -> String =
b=>"0"*31++b?1:0

print f(true)  // 00000000000000000000000000000001
print f(false) // 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Explanation**:

Returns the string `0` repeated 31 times followed by `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`. This does not work in v0.34.0 anymore because it removes the `+` operator for Strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

<sub>Saved two bytes thanks to Wernisch and my own lack of critical analysis before posting.</sub>
<sub>Saved two bytes by changing the formula completely</sub>

```
=BASE(OR(A1),2,32)
```

<s>It feels like there should be a shorter answer than this but I can't think of one.</s>
I found the shorter function that I felt must exist.

Comment: Can drop quotation marks for 2 bytes.
`=REPT(0,31)&1*A1` also handles falsy Empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 71 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(i)(format t "~v@{~A~:*~}" 31 0)(prin1(cond((null i) 0)(t 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDoAgDADArzRMrZPEzUmfYkCSJrUQBBcjX0e98ZzwmXpHv4eqEJAJQ8zHVqCAaddyt7XNQ3sMTBZGwpRZLbqoHlGrCDD9XcDSp2MAZaH@Ag)

Because nil is a falsey value and anything else is truthy:

(f nil) = 00000000000000000000000000000000

(f 123) = 00000000000000000000000000000001

(f t) =   00000000000000000000000000000001

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
q31Te[
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q31Te%5B&input=1)

Takes 1 for true and 0 for false. pads input with 31 0's on the left.

```
q     e# read input
31Te[ e# pad input with 31 0's on the left.
```

Comment: You could do `31T` instead of `GF+0` to save 1 byte

Comment: @BusinessCat Thanks, definite overthinking there!

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 24 bytes

```
1&u3I!|1^...0O;($\!vuO;@
```

Nonzero values are truthy in Cubix (as handled by `!`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/99QrdTYU7HGME5PT8/A31pDJUaxrNTf2uH/fwMA)

```
    1 &
    u 3
I ! | 1 ^ . . .
0 O ; ( $ \ ! v
    u O
    ; @
```

Explanation:

- `I` : read in input as a number
- `!|` : reflect go left if falsey, proceed if truthy

falsey:

- `I` : read in input; it's blank, so push `0`

truthy:

- `1` : push `1`

both branches reach here:

- `^3u1&\` : put `31` to the top of the stack and enter the loop

Loop:

- `!v0O;($\` : if top is zero, go south, otherwise push `0`, `O`utput as a number, pop (`;`), decrement (`(`), then `$`kip `\` and continue.

Finally:

- `;uO@` : pop the zero, `O`utput the `0/1`, and `@` exits.

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 21 bytes

```
[31|?A';`]~:|?!1$\?@0
```

### Explanation

```
[31|        DO 31 times
?           PRINT
 A          A$, which is later diefined as a literal 0 
            (represented as string, because QBasic spaces out printed numbers)
 ';`        Followed by a semicolon (to prevent newlines, tabs ect)
]           Close the loop
~:          IF the (numeric) input (is anything but 0)
|?!1$       THEN print a literal 1 (cast to string, to prevent the spacing thingy again)
\?@0        ELSE print a 0; Here we finally define A$. We could use it earlier,
            because the complie-process from QBIC to QBasic moves literal declarations to the
            top of the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 11 bytes

```
'0'x 31~+?*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf3UC9QsHYsE7bXuu/tUJxYqWCkkq8lUJ1moJKfK2SQlp@kUJIUWmqjoJbYk4xkDLQUTAEIgMgbVADYqkZWP8HAA)

- `'0' x 31` produces the first 31 zeroes.
- `*` is the argument to the function.  `?` coerces it to a boolean, and then `+` coerces that boolean into a number, either `0` or `1`, which is appended to the leading zeroes with `~`.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy - 17 bytes

A Groovy closure which takes a value and according to "groovy truth" outputs either a falsey or truthy value.

`{"0"*31+(it?1:0)}`

#### Explanation

So, all we do is emit a string with 31 zeroes and then append either 0 or 1 onto the end, depending upon whether the input is false or true, according to "groovy truth".

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/ErozYq)

Answer (score 0):

### [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 10 bytes

Sadly not as clever as I'd have liked, but it works.

```
(31#"0"),$
```

String-casts the input, and staples it to the end of 31 "0" chars

E.g.

```
k)(31#"0"),$1b
"00000000000000000000000000000001"
k)(31#"0"),$0b
"00000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 17 + 1 (-p) = 18 bytes

```perl
$_=0 x31 .($_&&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZAocLYUEFPQyVeTc1Q8/9/hX/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 20 bytes

```
{printf"%032d",!!$0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7PbsIwDMbvfoqPamhFgJR1N257gl04ckkbl0ZETpWEjjLt2Ttv2oQl@2D9vj/247Isn2PyUvpqbV4bd5Jqt1o9ma9leZcw484p1nkDKw5tsHJB8MIZics1CXobMh/I0N7Q1pB5DNGbzGXwcgYr8y8YY/bFT6qxbUcOjJ6qikD1ceDEzxkWebQdw7Zx4g2Zm3rVM4@73y7wgoFvf3YZJV0VavaNgi96dNVI39aHn@xHZ/gMiQU8saCLkr3TQHegbw) Here, to deal with multiple lines of input, I added `\n` to the printf modifier.

```
{                  }  For every input,
 printf"%    ",       prints, without a trailing newline,
         ​0            with leading zeros,
          32d         a 32-digit number,
               !!$0   and this number is the negative of the negative of the input.
                      In awk, only zero(s) and blank lines return false.
                      Anything else return true.
                      See examples in the TIO link above.
```

Another working code, with 24 bytes: `$0=sprintf("%032d",!!$0)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṙ32ṛ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKx7unGFs9HDn7CXFScnFUMEFS0KKSlMhbAA)

Input as a Python boolean: `True` or `False`.

##### Explanation

```python
      # Implicit input.
      # The interpreter implicitly converts
      # True and False to 1 and 0, since
      # integers look better than booleans.
Ṙ     # Convert this integer into a string.
 32ṛ  # And pad it with zeros on the left
      # until the length is equal to 32.
      # Implicit output.
```